# How do I smash open a Bottle?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

In TF2, I noticed that you can smash open the Demoman's Bottle when this tip showed up:

> The Demoman's Bottle does the same amount of damage regardless of whether it is smashed open or not.

However, I've been trying for a while, and I can't seem to break it open. I've tried swinging at players, walls, props, etc.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this tip outdated/incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They disabled the smashing of the bottle to avoid confusion. They saw it as being pointless mostly as it does the same damage regardless and it's just a visual effect.

Some people thought that it gave the weapon a greater crit chance or damage etc. and they just wanted to clear up the mess by removing it.

Comment: I don't think Valve ever said why they removed it... or even said whether or not it was intentional.

Comment: Oh yeah they never explicitly specified why they removed it, but that's most likely why they did, because confusion was a pretty big thing. If it wasn't intentional, then the reasons I provided would at least be the reasons for them not renewing it.